# Chrome hits a new level of cache madness in version 40

Tags: php, google-chrome

EDIT: I was looking at the wrong set of icons, the PNG's wern't background CSS divs, but rather loaded dynamically into the DOM via JS.

EDIT: I found pre-loading the PNG's in HTML in to a hidden DIV fixed the problem - however this wasn't a problem a few months ago when working on these same PNG's, so this issue still persists where I feel it shouldn't.

---

I'm editing various PNG files on my page.

The page is loaded with a random `?something` uri.

The PNG file is loaded via some HTML inserted in to the DOm via JS

I've added PHP no cache headers:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revawilidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

I've checked the apache settings and added this:

```
<filesMatch "\.(png|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

I have the F12 console open, and on the page, and in the resources, I'm still seeing the old image, if I click the link, chrome will bring up a new tab with the old image, if I then click F5 the new image loads - as of mid 2014 this was enough to refresh all pages using this resource (image), this no longer works.

When I repeat the last process, Chrome opens a new tab with the correct image! But the original page and resource still shows the old image.

I realize I can probably flush the cache, but haven't needed to until very late 2014. Is there a solution that doesn't involve flushing the cache manually every time I edit a PNG file? Or rather what is the solution for Chrome users who visit my site who are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: sounds a bit like you might have [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module) enabled. Does this only happen in Chrome? or also with other browsers?

Comment: I've had mod pagespeed on for about 6 months, i just disabled it, and restarted apache, Chrome still doing same problem, no problem in firefox. (I rechecked everything)